# How and where do I change my custom environment variables in the Godspeed framework?

Tags: .env

I have defined variables in a .env file, and I am attempting to access them from a `config/custom-environment-variables.yaml` file using their names. Here is the content of the [.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWRQR.png) and the [custom-environment-variables.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg0mo.png). In my `test.yaml` file, I am accessing these variables as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUIoJ.png).

Despite updating the values of the variables in the .env file, the changes are not being reflected when I access them in the `test.yaml` file. How can I ensure that the updated values of the variables are being retrieved?

Updated the .env varibles new values and tried to access it in the yaml file